# Подключения USB устройства к удаленному ПК

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, usb, share

Собственно задача в заголовке.

Вот аналоги
https://www.flexihub.com/
[USB over Ethernet](http://www.usb-over-ethernet.com/)
USB over Network

Есть с открытым исходным кодом
https://sourceforge.net/projects/usbip/
Но там сервер может работать только на линуксе и программа давно не обновлялась.

Сервер и клиент необходимо разработать под виндовс.

Может кто знает актуальные `open source` проекты вроде `usbip`?
Есть какой-то способ использовать драйвера с платных программ в своей? Даже если это запрещает лицензия.
Может есть какие-то статьи по принципу работы подобных приложений изнутри? 
В общем, любые советы по теме.

Comment: то, что (программа давно не обновлялась) не значит, что она плохая

Comment: согласен. но сервер работает только на линуксе

Comment: может проще на серваке поднять виртуалку с линухом и пробосить туда усб, так и безопаснее в некотором роде

Comment: кстати, если есть лишняя сетевуха, то и её туда можно пробросить

Comment: должна быть возможность установки и сервера и клиент на любой виндовс компьютер. соответственно виртуалка не подходит.

Comment: докер ?) https://stackoverflow.com/q/24225647

Comment: нет. принцип тот же но цель другая

Comment: не)) я всё о том же, о виртуалке )